# Firebase realtime database configure rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there a way to set the value of a key to null therefore delete it, if its new value is 0. For instance:

```
  "totalGames": {
    "ps5": 15,
    "ps4": 10,
    "ps3": 0
  }
```

I am using `increment(delta)` to update the values and it can be a negative value, that's why I want to set the rule. I didn't find a solution anywhere, does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Use a function listening to value changes of mentioned field and deleting it if necessary. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/ However, I sense that there might be a better approach when rethinking your use case carefully and change the overall design: Why would a value become negative, and why does the field need to be deleted in this case? Could the negative number ignored in the App?

Comment: It becomes negative because it is sold, the reason why i can't keep the negative values  is I have a cal to increment the values, and if the current value is -1 it will change to 0, and it doesn't reflect the correct value